# Fill value by default form in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a IdentityUser Model

I have a Manage View with 3 partials (each one have one viewmodel and controller) I want to enter on this view and see the forms with data filled of the model.

**ApplicationUser : IdentityUser (Model of my user)**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;

namespace MTGWeb.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public String Pais;
        public String Email;
        public DateTime UltimoLogin;
        public DateTime FechaRegistro;
        public String Tipo;
        public Boolean Activado;

    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**Manage (Main View)**

```
@using MTGWeb.Models;
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Administrar cuenta";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

<p class="text-success">@ViewBag.StatusMessage</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <p>Ha iniciado sesión como <strong>@User.Identity.GetUserName()</strong>.</p>

        @Html.Partial("_ChangePasswordPartial")

        @Html.Partial("_ChangeEmailPartial")

        @Html.Partial("_OtherFieldsPartial")

    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**_ChangeEmailPartial**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@model MTGWeb.Models.ManageUserViewModelEmailChange

@using (Html.BeginForm("ManageEmail", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Formulario para cambiar email</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OldEmail, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OldEmail, new { @class = "form-control", Value = Model.OldEmail})
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewEmail, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewEmail, new { @class = "form-control" }) 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmEmail, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfirmEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Cambiar email" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Controller - ManageEmail**

```
// Cambia el email
// POST: /Account/ManageEmail
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ManageEmail(ManageUserViewModelEmailChange model)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");


    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)//Si no hay errores en la validación que hace la clase (Datatype, length, required, etc..)
    {

        if (model.OldEmail.Equals(model.NewEmail) && model.OldEmail.Equals(user.Email))
        {
            user.Email = model.NewEmail;
            IdentityResult success = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);

            if (success.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangeEmailSuccess });
            }

        }

    }

    //Si el modelo no es válido o no el cambio no ha tenido exito
    return View(model);
}
```

I have 2 more controllers for others partials, but this is usefull for the example. These `Model.OldEmail` is null and causes a `Nullreference` error, Where I have to fill it? I guess that this have to be filled in `AccountController/Manage`, but.. How can I send it to the partials?

I am new on MVC and .NET, I used to work with Java, and I am stucked in this (Is a testing project purposes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the model you want the partials to show into the partials as an argument
you will need to add a viewmodel containing the models you want to show to the host view.

eg

```
  @Html.Partial("_ChangePasswordPartial",Model.ChangePAsswordViewModel)
```

Model is a property on Controller (which your manage controller will inherit from)

You pass the viewmodel into the manage view from the controller in `return View(YourViewModelInstance)` from your Manage controller method.

you also need to add a reference to that model in your manage form like you have in your partials
Eg

```
 @model MTGWeb.Models.ManageViewModel
```

your manage viewmodel might look something like

```
public class ManageViewModel
{
    public ChangePasswordViewModel ChangePasswordViewModel{get;set;}
    public NextViewModel NextViewModel{get;set;}
    public AnotherViewModel NextViewModel{get;set;}
}
```